# Windows 2012 IPv6 DNS

Tags: dns, ipv6, windows-server-2012

I've decided to host my own internal authoritative DNS server for a made-up private domain used internally at home.

I did so, and all my statically assigned linux boxes are happy and using it without a problem after modifying their search domains.

I have one statically assigned Windows 2012 system.  I changed it's IP settings and set the DNS suffix.   But, it simply doesn't work, as it tries to use some made up IPv6 DNS server.   I do not have IPv6 enabled internally, so it's not getting this information from any kind of DHCPv6 system.

[image: IP settings]

This is the address it assigns.

So when I try to resolve hosts on command line I get results like this:

```
C:\Users\Me>nslookup alpha
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  fdc5:cbad:cebc::1

*** UnKnown can't find alpha: No response from server
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have IPv6 enabled? Your screenshot clearly shows an IPv6 address from the same `fdc5:cbad:cebc::/64` prefix, and even DHCPv6 lease information (an 136-year-long lease at that).

Comment: Ugh!  Thanks for the tip.  I thought it was disabled on a router/wifi device I was previously using, but it was not.